# Use a different font (ttf) with skak/NFSS problems

Tags: fonts, fontspec, xskak, skak

Fonts on LaTex have always left me confused, so I've defaulted to xeLaTex in the past. Is there any simple way to use fontspec and *LaTex to use alternate fonts with with skak (or xskak)?

This would be far preferable to the method described in chessfss, which seems to be stuck in the nfss-era.

I've gotten most of the way through the chessfss documentation, generating my needed pfb files via fontforge and the tfm files via ttf2tfm (could've done that with fontforge, but found ttf2tfm first).

Unfortunately, I can't find nfss.tex on my system (or any info on how to install it).

Comment: I can't see any reference to `nfss.tex` in the chessfss  pdf documentation on ctan? ("NFSS" is just the standard font handling in latex2e)

Comment: Which font are you trying to use?

Comment: unicode is not really suitable for chess. There are number of unicode positions for the figures but the rest of the symbols is not encoded. So all chess fonts that I know have the symbols at more or less arbitrary positions (e.g. the queen on "q" (english font author) or "d" (german font author) and one can't avoid to reencode them to standarize this positions. That's the main point of chessfss.

Comment: I was hoping to use Good Companion (http://www.enpassant.dk/chess/fontimg/gc.htm), as it's pieces are very close to what I see in a lot of print books. As you said, it's encoding is rather random. (the long goal is of training the tensorflow chess bot to be more accurate with print, rather than online, chess boards. Then, with a little bit of modified code, I can do batch-conversion of problems into fen strings for input into Anki, the fancy flashcard program.  https://github.com/Elucidation/tensorflow_chessbot )

Comment: You should notify me with @UlrikeFischer if you want me to see your comment. Beside this: The link to the font is dead, but if you already have a pfb and a tfm then the rest is easy. (I can't say if the font contains the glyph for boards, the image shows only figurines.)